# How to fetch dictionaries within dictionaries in a JSON string?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Graph API I want to get location data.

```
{
   "name": "Joe Smith",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/joey",
   "location": {
      "id": "105590706140862",
      "name": "Fairfield, Iowa"
   }
}
```

I can take this object and do things like `object["name"]` to get the name Joe Smith.  But how do I get the name "Fairfield, Iowa"?

Comment: Note that you should put the language you're talking about in the question--not just tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import json

json_text = """
{
    "name": "Joe Smith",
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/joey",
    "location": {
        "id": "105590706140862",
        "name": "Fairfield, Iowa"
    }
}"""

obj = json.loads(json_text)
print obj["location"]["name"]
```

Comment: For anyone using Facebook's Graph API in Python, you can skip loading it as a json object.